# Paypal Payments Pro Sandbox error We’re sorry, we can’t complete your payment now. Please try again later

Tags: php, paypal, paypal-sandbox

I am integrating Paypal using my Sandbox account.

My integration is working when using my PayPal account but when using sandbox, it showed below error:
When form is submit so that time this error is occurs.

Error: Error Processing Payment
We’re sorry, we can’t complete your payment now. Please try again later.

I have already tried to make simple html code posted but sandbox is not working. So what's the problem? Please send me any idea.
My sandbox paypal id is a business account.

So please tell me what is wrong?

Answer (score 0):

It might be of your browser cookies or cache issue, clear-up everything and for better results try using the upgraded version of Chrome or FF.

Cheers!